# How to rewrite the toString method to display my stack?

Tags: java, stack, tostring

How can I rewrite the toString method on my stack to display it in output.
I have the following code:

```
public class Stack {

    public int [] elements;
    public int top;

    public Stack (int e) {
        elements = new int [e];
        top = -1;
    }

    public void insert (int e) {
        if (! isFull ()) {
            top ++;
            elements [top] = e;
        }

    }

    public boolean isEmpty () {
        return top == -1;
    }

    public boolean isFull () {
        return this.top == this.elements.length - 1;
    }

    public int remove () {
        if (! isEmpty ()) {
            return elements [top--];
        }
        return 0;

    }

    public int size () {
        return this.elements.length;
    }
}
```

In this case I wanted to display my instantiated stack in class main

Using Stack from Java itself is already created a structure where the stacks are printed in the output as: [1, 2, 3] or [1] if it has only one value.

Inserting the toString:

```
@Override
    public String toString () {
        return "stack {" + "elements =" + elements + ", top =" + top + '}';
    }
```

Only the name of the class is left.
I would like something that displays the array correctly
Can someone help me??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Arrays#toString` which returns a `string` representation of the contents of the `specified array`.

```
   @Override
    public String toString () {
        return "stack {" + "elements =" + Arrays.toString(elements) + ", top =" + top + '}';
    }
```

Above to String method returns String in the format like below :

```
stack {elements =[1, 2, 3], top =3}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public String toString () {
        return "stack {" + "elements =" + Arrays.toString( elements  ) + ", top =" + top + '}';
}
```